# How can output Title, Email and phone from User Profiles

Tags: javascript, web-services, spservices

I found some code that outputs from user profiles and works but it only outputs Manager. How can this be changed to output Title, Email and Phone number?

```
  var managerName;
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
    async: false,
    AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Manager')").each(function() {
        managerName = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
        alert(managerName );
      });
    }
  });
```

I've tried changing the code section below but this doesnt work at all.

```
completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    var oTitle = ($(this).attr("Title"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
var user = {};
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
    async: false,
    AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").each(function() {
        user[$(this).find("Name").text()] = $(this).find("Value").text();
        //user.AccountName
        //user.PreferredName
        //user.WorkEmail
        //user.WorkPhone
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tried Alert(user.WorkPhone) and recieved numerous alerts mostly with undefined then I got some real data. Seems to be in a loop !

Comment: Yes. You should place the alerts after the `each` loop. Once the loop completes, it will have data for the comments I placed inside the loop.

Comment: use try and catch to stop Alert, because some profiles not have workphone... or try show me your code for verify if is correct...

Comment: I have it working now, Could you explain a bit more (with code) the try and catch pls?

Comment: You don't need to use try catch.. instead you can check whether its null or undefined using if condition ... `if(user.WorkPhone != undefined).. then use it`